# Set is_staff to true for new users that created new accounts from CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-authentication

I am having problem with Django.

I am using UserCreationForm and generic CreateView in order for people to sign up and create an account. The code is as follows:

Custom form:

```
class SignUpCustomUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

View:

```
class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = SignUpCustomUserForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'
```

I do not have a model since I am using CreateView which basically handles the model.

I want to automatically set every new created account as staff, but I can not figure out how to do it. Basically, I am working on a form which users can use to create an account with is_staff privileges and they can use those accounts to login to /admin (the default django admin).

I tried setting model.is_staff to true in the Meta class inside the form class, but it didn't work out.

Any advice or ideas is welcomed.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `is_staff` to `True` in the `.form_valid(…)` method:

```
class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = SignUpCustomUserForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.is_staff = True
        return super().form_valid(form)
```